# Как создать камеру с упреждением по управлению в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно создать камеру в 2D игре, которая следит и за персонажем, и за мышкой. Камера перемещается при движении персонажа и одновременно наводится на курсор - направление взгляда игрока. Как реализовать это в unity, пробовал Cinemachine, но там при создании слежении за двумя объектами постоянно меняется размер(удаление) камеры, а мне требуется сохранение одного и того же масштаба.

Comment: Как вариант, перемещать камеру на середину треугольника, где вершины: положение персонажа, мышка и вектор движения/взгляда персонажа.

Comment: Возможно, достаточно и двух точек, но как поместить камеру между ними - через положения этих двух точек в Update?